# Is there any way to scrap value for a webpage which fetch its vaue from API

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project and I have to fetch '6596626' from the source code of url= "https://www.screener.in/company/ITC/consolidated/".
The value is not visible on web page making it difficult to extract using xpath.
The below code is a part of page's source code which has the value which I want to extract.

```
   <div
     data-company-id="1552"
     data-warehouse-id="6596626"
     data-user-is-registered="true"
     data-consolidated="true"
     id="company-info">
    </div>
```

This was the code I tried on, I was expecting to extract the value straight from the source code but with no result.

```py
    from urllib import request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from lxml import etree

    symbol=input("Enter symbol of the company\n")
    response = request.urlopen("https://www.screener.in/company/"+symbol+"/consolidated/")
    page_source = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
    id=soup.get_text('data-warehouse-id')
    print(id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('#company-info')['data-warehouse-id'])


main('https://www.screener.in/company/ITC/consolidated/')
```

Output:

```
6596626
```